# How to hide Android Studio feedback smiley-icons in status bar "click to let google know .."?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Is there some way to hide those ***smiley-face icons*** after you have left feedback?

They are distracting .. especially since I already honored them.

I clicked the happy-face after I was logged into a Gmail user account in the IDE.  However it still shows those 2 icons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Data Sharing and then uncheck data sharing. then restart the android studio and the smiley will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions, you can right-click them and hide them

(tested on Arctic Fox 2020.3.1)